# How to align an image-button with another button?

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I am able to create a commandbutton with image in visualforce page. But how to align it with another button? 
This is the current result:

[image: command button with image not aligned with another button]

Here is the code

```
<apex:outputPanel id="top" layout="block" style="margin:5px;padding:10px;padding-top:2px;">          
    <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton styleClass="updateBookingButton" id="btnUpdateBooking" value="Update" action="{!updateBookingTask}"></apex:commandButton></span>
    <span style="padding-left:5px"><apex:commandButton styleClass="resetBookingButton" id="btnResetBooking" value="Reset" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){return false};" action="{!resetBookingTask}"></apex:commandButton></span>
    <span style="padding-left:5px;"><apex:commandButton styleClass="refreshBookingButton" id="btnRefreshBooking" value="Refresh" action="{!refreshBookingTask}"  image="{!URLFOR($Resource.refresh_icon)}" style="width: 15px; height: 13px;"></apex:commandButton></span>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I also tried to add margin and display it with inline-block but the button still not aligned with other button.
Basically, I want to align the refresh button with other button

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `vertical-align:bottom;` to your CSS.

```
<span style="padding-left:5px;"><apex:commandButton styleClass="refreshBookingButton" id="btnRefreshBooking" value="Refresh" action="{!refreshBookingTask}"  image="{!URLFOR($Resource.refresh_icon)}" style="width: 15px; height: 13px;vertical-align:bottom;"></apex:commandButton></span>
```